# CakePHP - dynamically change core.php variable 'imageBaseUrl'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP app, I have a model Acccount.  I  want each account to have its own subfolder in the webroot/img folder.  I can create the subfolders no problem.

The challenge is universally identifying which is the current default path.  I can get a account id from the Auth.User.account_id.

Rather than modify the img path in every View where it is required by introducing the Auth.User.account_id, I thought it would be better to  dynamically change the default image path by reading a value in core.php file and change the 'imageBaseUrl' there so it is available throughout the app.

However, I am haven't found any documentation on how to bring variables into the core.php file.  I understand it is a file meant to deliver variables to the app so perhaps it isn't possible.

I have tried to deliver Configure::write value as shown below, but that doesn't appear to be read in the core.php file.

```
* Web path to the public images directory under webroot.
* If not set defaults to 'img/'
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'img/'.Configure::write('imageurl').'/');
```

Is there some way to bring a variable into core.php file, or perhaps there is another method that can dynamically change the image path dependent on application variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value for `App.imageBaseUrl` as required in your `AppController`'s `beforeRender()` callback. No need to change it before that point since the value is only required in views. Plus you will have the session component available.

Comment: It also works in AppController beforeFilter() so same question about this; where is 'proper' or 'best' (most efficient?) place to change the  'img value in Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'img')? I suppose if i want to pass new folder to controller, beforeFilter is best. Otherwise it doesn't matter? Thx

Comment: Since this relates to view doing it in beforeRender() is the proper place. It's more efficient too since it avoids an extra statement for POST request when you generally just redirect after performing required operation in action. If you wanted the info about new folder available in action then you would do it in beforeFilter() but really don't see why an action would care about asset location.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to modify core.php. Try this code snippet at beginning of your app/Config/bootstrap.php file:

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'img/' .
    (CakeSession::check('Auth.User') ? CakeSession::read('Auth.User.account_id') . '/' : ''));
```

Comment: This worked so not sure why it was downvoted. However, it also works in the AppController beforeRender() as ADmad describes.  Can someone explain the downvote and/or the proper place to do this eg AppController beforeRender or bootstrap.php?